# Watson Data Kits API

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson

Is there a list of advanced filtering and sorting of parameters for the Watson Data Kits API, specifically the Travel Data kit? I want to be able to limit responses to certain keywords. I would also like to be able to combine various flags, to really optimize my results.

Comment: Did you try searching on " Watson Knowledge Kit API filtering"? Looks like the IBM API docs talk about this. This question is a bit too broad and unrelated to a specific question about code for SO I think.

Answer (score 0):

**As for your first question**,
Use `` `f` `` to add the filter option to a parameter. This option indicates that the condition set by the parameter it prefaces must be met in order to be included in the result.

Note: Each parameter has a `` `f` `` option added by default.

Example:

In /attractions?address=nyc&attraction_keyword=`` `f` ``theater, the response will return only attractions whose name includes the keyword theater.

**For your second question,**

Note: the rank option must come last. address, location, and radius parameters only have `` `f` `` option available.

Example: - In /attractions?address=nyc&attraction_keyword=`` `u!25` ``theater, the response will include attractions in results whose names do not match the keyword theater AND have the rank value of attraction_keyword set to 25.